# Moving signal power normalization

Tags: normalization, matched-filter, software-defined-radio, gnuradio

I am using matched filters using GNU Radio to extract from noise a CW Morse signal. The filter actually performs pretty well in various SNR environments. My problem is that the threshold upon I decide for a presence or absence of a CW transmission vary with different SNR/CW frequency/WPM/incoming signal amplitude setups.

Conventional normalization methods, (eg dividing with the max value) are not applicable since the program runs continuously and the max value is not known a priori.
I believe that a moving normalization scheme should deal with this problem. In the past, for preamble detection I have used the moving normalized autocorrelation method that is depicted below (`C` and `P` are moving sums). I tried to adapt this approach in my case but with no luck. [image: autocorrelation normalization]

My question is, if there is a method to normalize either the output signal power of the matched filter or the input signal itself, so I can rely on a one predefined decision threshold for CW signal presence/absence.

Comment: I would suggest looking into GnuRadio's AGC block.

Comment: @MBaz thanks. I thought about the solution of AGC. Hoverer the parameters of the AGC is a process of try-and-error and I would like to know if someone suggests a better method.